# How to ensure something only happens once in a request?

Tags: apex, force.com, controller, visualforce

If I have a page which include multiple components which means that multiple back end controllers get invoked on page load. How do I ensure that a piece of business functionality only happens once?

By once I mean once per page load - of the entire page which will have multiple components..

Comment: Can you elaborate? Once per page load, per controller, per user session, etc . . .

Comment: A static variable is unique per execution context. If across requests then you will need to write state to a custom setting or custom object.

Answer (score 2):

Further to @techtrekker's comment, if you are persisting state to a custom object or setting for use with multiple requests that are likely to be occurring simultaneously you will want to ensure that only one request (execution context) can update that record at a time.

See the `FOR UPDATE` SOQL locking statement keywords to get a database write lock - [Locking Statements](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm). This will prevent subsequent requests from getting the state until the first request has finished updating it.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a very simple utility class called RecursionUtil. It keeps a static `Map<String, Integer>` of method calls (or whatever level of gate granularity you want to enforce) to times called. It has a method called `Boolean tooDeep(String key, Integer maxDepth)` which checks that map for the counter, increments it by one, and then returns true if the current execution is larger than `maxDepth`.

This can be used for your case - only allowing a piece of functionality to be called once - or in other cases where you want to stop more than N calls occurring to prevent infinite recursion, stack/heap overflow, etc.

Obviously this only works within the scope of one request, but I think that's what you were asking.